# How to limit the amount of information copied from a folder in batch?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I am looking for a way to copy an unknown amount of files with specific extensions and the problem is that the amount is unknown, and their size is unknown. I would like the copy process to stop once a certain amount of gigabytes has been reached... how would I go about doing that?

```
for /R "C:\" %%G in (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) do copy "%%G" "D:\E"
```

That is what I have so far.

Comment: Accumulate the size of each file (`%%~zG`) before copy and break the `for` when it reach your limit. You need to adjust the sizes to the 32-bits integer range of `set /A` command if the limit is greater than 16 gigabytes.